# How can I make one Tailwind Class more specific without exclamation mark?

Tags: tailwind-css

I can force override class specificity like this in Tailwind CSS 3.0.

```html
<div class="p-1 !p-2">test</div>
```

However, I occasionally want to override the `!p-2`, but extra exclamation mark
`!!p-3` is not enabled; how can I do this?

Comment: Not with a help of Tailwind. `!` sign is just CSS `!important` flag. So you can specify which class to use with `if-else` condition depends on stack you use

Answer (score 0):

"!" is the !important in CSS.
It is to override the class one position lower line in the .css

If it is a responsive website, you can use breakpoints

```
<div class="p-1 sm:p-2 md:p-3">test</div>
```

Otherwise, some programming language must be used.

```
<?php $className = 1 < 2 ? 'true-class' : 'false-class'; ?>
<div class="<?php echo $className; ?>" />
```

[Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html)

etc... search: *your programing language* **css class bidding**